# Type Mismatch Error 13 Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hi Please help me on this error.

```
i = 0
Dim ci As Integer
pi = Array(0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9)

ci = 1
For i = 0 To UBound(Criteria)
    Windows("Demo.xlsx").Activate
    Worksheets("Raw_Data").Activate
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H" & LastRow).AutoFilter field:=TaskType, Criteria1:=Criteria(i)
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H" & LastRow).AutoFilter field:=Status, Criteria1:="=Completed"
    Columns(Elapse).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(fname).Activate
    Sheets("Calculation").Select

        For J = 1 To UBound(Criteria)
            Columns(ci).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            For ri = 2 To 5

            MsgBox "=ROUND(PERCENTILE(A:A," & pi(ri - 2) & "),2)"
            Range(Columns(ci + 1) & ri).Value = "=ROUND(PERCENTILE(A:A," & pi(ri - 2) & "),2)"
            Next ri
             Range(Columns(ci + 1) & (ri)).Value = "=ROUND(AVERAGE(A:A),2)"
             Range(Columns(ci + 1) & (ri + 1)).Value = "=ROUND(MAX(A:A),2)"
        Next J
        ci = ci + 2

Next i
```

I am geeting Error on this line Range(Columns(ci + 1) & ri).Value. I tried to debug but didnt got any solution.

Comment: When you get the error what values are in ci and ri?

Comment: range expects a letter not a number for column (to use column you would have to use something to get the letter of columns()), try using cells(ri,ci + 1).Value

Comment: yes it worked, but the the formula "=ROUND(PERCENTILE(A:A," & pi(ri - 2) & "),2)" is should take alternate columns like C:C, E,E,G:G, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can use `Columns` as a `Range` in this form:

`Range(Columns(ci + 1) & ri).Value = "=ROUND(MAX(A:A),2)`

You can use something like this:

`Columns(ci + 1 + ri).Value = "=ROUND(MAX(A:A),2)"`

But fill all column with formula is not good idea, better use range a little differently:

`Range(Cells(1, ri), Cells(LastRow, ri)).Value = "=ROUND(MAX(A:A),2)"`

Perhaps the last example will be helpful